# Like Google Maps - Just local

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I was looking to find a solution to our product. We have a geo-location, on a web based dashboard that does not have internet connection.

I was looking for a product that allows you to have local maps and a script, I found OpenLayers which seems cool although weights 22gb.

Do you know if there are other solutions to generate map locally that takes less space?

Comment: Where's the 22GB come from? 10mb download i found? probably has'nt got maps I assume...

Comment: "on a web based dashboard that does not have internet connection".  So its an intranet website?  Any dynamic mapping solution is going to have reams of data backing it up, geodata takes up a lot of harddisk space.  22gb is nothing if you are serving it up off a dedicated box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume correctly, you are basically looking for an alternative to Google Maps, i.e. an alternative mapping service where you can use your own local data, right?

Now, based on your question, its hard to tell whether you

1. Want to develop something for yourself or buy/adopt an already implemented software
2. Are looking for the serverside (i.e. tiling/caching engine, geospatial database, etc) or for the clientside or for both

I could give you an example of a possible configuration if you want to develop a clientside application yourself, but that might not be what you are exactly looking for.

For the serverside, you could use [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/), backed by a [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/) spatial database (PostGIS is an enhancement of PostgreSQL), and then use a client side Javascript framework BASED on OpenLayers to develop your client application (i.e., the map viewer), such as [Fusion](http://research.dmsolutions.ca/projects/fusion/), which is also based on the MooTools Javascript Library. You could also natively develop with OpenLayers. There are a lot of possibilities in the Open Source world, it just depends on the skill and time you have.

Also, have a look at [OSGEO](http://www.osgeo.org/), in the right sidebar you'll find a lot of projects that are hosted by them. It definetely is your first address for Open Source web mapping solutions.